# How to specify regex in istio's uri

Tags: istio

### Expectations.

- /hoge/?xxx=xxx
  Transition the above PATH to port xxxx

### Current configuration

```
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            regex: '\/hoge\/\?.*$'
          port: xxxx
```

### What's happening.

Regex is not working.
I thought about using queryParams, but it is not configured because some keys are present and some are not.
How can I get regex to work?

### What we tried.

- /hoge/?.*$
- "/hoge/?.*$"
- /hoge/?